# rbind for dataframes with different number of rows

Tags: r

I try to rbind 2 different dataframes with different number of columns.

In order to succeed this I remove the col names from the second df but the rbind is not successful

Here is what I try to do and what I receive

```
setDT(df_test)[, N:= 1:.N, url]
> df_test <- dcast(df_test, url~N, value.var=c("test_main"))
> names(df_test_not) <- NULL
> df_test_all <- rbind(df_test, df_test_not)
 Hide Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : 
  Item 2 has 2 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 36 columns. If instead you need to fill missing columns, use set argument 'fill' to TRUE. 
4 rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) 
3 data.table::.rbind.data.table(...) at <text>#1
2 rbind(deparse.level, ...) 
1 rbind(df_test, df_test_not)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rbind.fill` as follows:

```
library(plyr)
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 5:1)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 6:15)
df_combined <- rbind.fill(df1, df2)
print(df_combined)
```